# Why can't I use my domain name as Facebook web address?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to set up a Facebook page for my website, let's call it `mywebsite.com`.

I'm trying to use my domain name as *web address*:

> Choose a unique Facebook web address to make it easier for people to find your Page. Once this is set, it can only be changed once.

When I enter `mywebsite.com`, I get the following message:

> mywebsite.com is taken. Please choose another Facebook web address.

Too bad, I thought. Already reserved. So I tried with one of its subdomains:

> fr.mywebsite.com is taken. Please choose another Facebook web address.

Basically, it looks like anything looking like a domain name (containing dots) is "taken":

> dfsjkfdhkjsqhkjdfkqsdf.com is taken. Please choose another Facebook web address.

Is it a misleading error message to say that Facebook actually forbids dots in web addresses, or is there a specific place to create Facebook pages for websites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the **Facebook Help-Center** regarding your [Facebook Web Address](https://www.facebook.com/help/329992603752372), this is the section that is relevant to your issue:

> #### What are the guidelines around creating a custom username for my Page or profile?
>
> Here are a few things to keep in mind when you create a custom username:
>
> - You can't claim a username someone else is already using.
> - Choose a username you'll be happy with for the long term. Usernames are not transferable, and you can only change your username once.
> - Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a period (".").
> - Periods (".") and capitalization don't count as a part of a username. For example, johnsmith55, John.Smith55 and john.smith.55 are
>   all considered the same username.
> - Usernames must be at least 5 characters long and ***can't contain generic terms or extensions (ex: .com, .net)***.
> - You must be an admin to choose a username for a Page.
> - Your username must adhere to the Facebook Statement of Rights and Responsibilities.

#### In Summary

You are **not allowed to use .com** in your Facebook Vanity URL.
Try entering just "mywebsite" instead.

Comment: Missed that part. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Funnily it does accept local extensions, such as `.fr`.

Comment: This is good to know! Thanks for the information ;)